# JTextField and JButton are not visible when I call the class from another class

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I have a main class where only call another class where is a window, when I run from the class of the windows it looks normal, but whan I run from the main class, one `JFieldText` and a `JButton` are not visible until I move the cursor over the `JButton` or click in the `JFieldText`.

The code for the main class is:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    windowMain vp = new windowMain();
    vp.vPrincipal.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

and the code for the window class is:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class windowMain {

    JFrame vPrincipal;
    private JTextField tfRutaArchivo;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    windowMain window = new windowMain();
                    window.vPrincipal.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public windowMain() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        vPrincipal = new JFrame();
        vPrincipal.setTitle("Ordenar Archivo POO 4to. Cuatrimestre");
        vPrincipal.setSize(600,450);
        vPrincipal.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        vPrincipal.setVisible(true);
        vPrincipal.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar mbPrincipal = new JMenuBar();
        vPrincipal.setJMenuBar(mbPrincipal);

        JMenu mPrincipal = new JMenu("Menu");
        mbPrincipal.add(mPrincipal);

        JMenuItem miExit = new JMenuItem("Salir");
        miExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        mPrincipal.add(miExit);

        JMenu mHelp = new JMenu("Ayuda");
        mbPrincipal.add(mHelp);

        JMenuItem miAbout = new JMenuItem("Acerca de ...");
        miAbout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                jdAbout popAcerca;
                popAcerca = new jdAbout();
                popAcerca.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        mHelp.add(miAbout);
        vPrincipal.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        tfRutaArchivo = new JTextField();
        tfRutaArchivo.setBounds(21, 11, 399, 20);
        vPrincipal.getContentPane().add(tfRutaArchivo);
        tfRutaArchivo.setColumns(10);

        JButton btBuscarArchivo = new JButton("Buscar");
        btBuscarArchivo.setBounds(473, 10, 89, 23);
        vPrincipal.getContentPane().add(btBuscarArchivo);
     }
    }
```

When I run from the class of the window it looks like this:
[image: Run from windows class]

When run from the main class look like this:
[image: run from main class]

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It works for me, but I would recommend to 1) call `vPrincipal.setVisible(true);` **after** you added all components (or not at all, as you do `vp.vPrincipal.setVisible(true);` manually already) and 2) Also wrap the `windowMain vp = new windowMain(); vp.vPrincipal.setVisible(true);` in the `Main`-class into `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Get rid of the call to `setVisible` (`vPrincipal.setVisible(true);`) in `initialize` or make it the last thing that is called. Prefer `pack` over `setSize`

Comment: Thanks a lot works adding the setVisible after all components.  :)

Comment: Building your interface must occur in a call to `invokeLater`(as stated by @LuxxMiner - this is a requirement), if not, incoherent drawings can occur.